# fastest way to insert just a few rows over thousands of querys MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have thousands of insert rows for products however I also need to insert suppliers information at the same time.

There is no way to query just what the suppliers information is out of the system I am exporting the information from (name, supplier number etc) apart from getting it attached to every single product the product export.

Unless I go through every product information export, there is no way to be sure that all suppliers have been updated/ inserted.

To put it in perspective there is only about 5 suppliers to about 2000 products.

What is the most optimized way to insert the suppliers, rather than check every single time if the supplier exists because almost all of the time it will?

What is the best way to do this?

I'm using pdo and prepared statements and transactions...

Comment: A unique constraint on the table comes to mind, which would prevent the insertion of records containing duplicate values.  This would happen at the database level, freeing (at least partially) your PHP layer from needing to manage this.

Comment: you can use bulk insert query using `INSERT INTO tablename(fields) values(values of fist record), (values of second recors)` and so on...

Comment: Yeah I know how to insert I just want to do it the fastest way for a couple of records

Answer (score 1):

1. Select all the suppliers
2. Go with inserting the product data

   - check whether you have the particular supplier

     - if not, then insert it
   - insert the product
3. Collect supplier data for all the product inserts
4. Upon finishing inserting products, loop over suppliers and update them

Answer (score 0):

Your request it's not very clear (at least for me).

You mean that, **every time you insert a new product on DB you want an easier way to check if the product's supplier already exists on database**?

If it is so, every time you insert a new Product **you can insert/update supplier's info** with the following **statement**:

```
REPLACE INTO suppliers (name, number, ...) VALUES ([name], [number], ...);
```

This statement does the following:

- If current supplier:

  - does not exists on `DB` it will save it on `suppliers` table.
  - if already exists on `DB` it will update supplier's `DB` data with provided info.

I think it's the quicker way for you to do what you want.

Comment: He clearly stated that there are few suppliers per thousands products, means running an extra query "every time you insert a new Product" is not the quicker way

Comment: I'm not sure about that.

He said "__Unless I go through every product information export, there is no way to be sure that all suppliers have been updated/ inserted.__" and with that he means that everytime he inserts a new product he must verify if product's supplier already exists on `DB` so he can know if the (new) supplier must be inserted or not ...

Comment: ... then he asked: "__What is the most optimized way to insert the suppliers, rather than check every single time if the supplier exists because almost all of the time it will?__"

With my suggestion he delegates that task to mysql, i.e, mysql has the responsability to check if given supplier already exists on `DB` and take the correct action depending on result.

Plus, if he's using transactions - as he stated - I can assure that performance it'll not be an issue.

Comment: Sorry to clarify,

Comment: Sorry to clarify, I cannot export the suppliers, I can only export the products, which has the supplier tacked on the product export.

Because I can't do a dump of the suppliers, the only way I can get the suppliers information is when I get it attached to the products export.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: Jonny, can you provide an example (using pseudo code) on what you want/need, showing us the kind of data you receive and how out want to treat it?